# How to add 3rd party click tags

Tags: joomla, click, change-tracking

My client has supplied me with tracking code to track impressions and clicks of a page skin design that I have placed on my joomla website. I have added this code to the module that is displaying the graphics but the client reports that no tracking is occurring. I can see a timestamp tag in the code but are not sure how any of this really works.

```
  //To track Impressions use the following URL:
http://bs.serving-sys.com/example/adServer.bs?cn=tf&c=19&mc=i4p&pli=5460041&PluID=0&ord=[timestamp]&rtu=-1

//To track Clicks use the following URL:
//Note: Please ensure that you implement a click tracking URL only in the clicks location in your ad server, 
//and an impression tracking URL only in the impression tracking location.
//Incorrect implementation of these URLs will result in major billing and reporting discrepancies.
http://bs.serving-sys.com/example/adServer.bs?cn=tf&4=20&mc=click&pli=5460041&PluID=0&ord=[timestamp]
```

Comment: I do not see any code. Where is the code example?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the current timestamp with `<?php echo time(); ?>`.
So if your tracking code is working correct, you should be able to track those clicks after replacing the [timestamp].

Example:

```
<a href="http://bs.serving-sys.com/example/adServer.bs?cn=tf&4=20&mc=click&pli=5460041&PluID=0&ord=[timestamp]" />
```

comes to

```
<a href="http://bs.serving-sys.com/example/adServer.bs?cn=tf&4=20&mc=click&pli=5460041&PluID=0&ord=<?php echo time(); ?>" />
```